# FastCGI Error 0x80004005

Tags: php, iis, server, fastcgi

We have php 5.4.38 installed on IIS6.
I have a test.php script. There is one single row in it:

`echo "test";`

I use my browser and visit the page. I see "test" on it. Ok. Then I reload the page several times and it still shows what it should. But after 15 or maybe 20 times of fast page reloading, I get FastCgi Error. After this happens, for about 5 seconds no page on this server can be shown. We tried to reach it from client computers from different IP-s, different networks. "Everything" just stops. After 5 seconds it works again.

What can we do to solve this problem?

When error appears, this is what the server returns:

> FastCGI Error
>
> The FastCGI Handler was unable to process the request. Error Details:
>
> The FastCGI process has failed frequently recently. Try the request
>   again in a while Error Number: -2147467259 (0x80004005). Error
>   Description: Unspecified error HTTP Error 500 - Server Error. Internet
>   Information Services (IIS)